# Creating page templates with image placeholders

Tags: images

I am creating my own theme and in the design I received for the theme I have a few pages which have 2 images of different dimensions. One is at the top (like a banner of sorts) while the other one is on the right side of the content text. So underneath the banner there will be two columns, one for the content and one for the image.

I was thinking of maybe creating a page template for these specific pages (or maybe make it a custom page template selectable from the admin interface).

The thing I am not sure about is the cleanest way to have these two image placeholders included in the template and clearly editable from the Admin interface. What I have in mind is maybe having a meta box or something saying Page Images, enabling the user to choose the images he wants for the top and for the side. There is also the extra complication that one image is landscape and the other is portrait, so ideally there is some kind of resizing or cropping (although I could in theory crop each image to all the possible required sizes, and then pick the needed one depending on which area of the page I am rendering).

I know that there are some generic ways I can do this through plugins. I an use the Attachments plugin, but it won't be clear to the user that the first is for the top banner, and the second for the side image, (and the rest if any are unused). I know there is also the ACF plugin, although not so sure whether it offers what I need.

Is there a clean and simple way to achieve this? Ideally I don't use any plugins for this, its just something specific to my theme... but I'll bite the bullet if there is no other option. What alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACF, which you mentioned, would be the easiest/fastest way to get this done. A post by default has a single thumbnail, no magic option to add another with less work than what ACF does.

If the design allows for it, you could also insert the second image straight into content and align it to the right.

Comment: Thanks. Yes ACF looks like the best option so far, but wanted to explore if there is anything else more programmatic I can do natively. I want to avoid inserting straight into content because the user will be confused and there is a set of pages that all need to look the same with this layout. There is also the extra complication that to achieve responsiveness I might need to use `background: cover` to ensure the full width and height of the 2nd column is covered while retaining aspect ratio.